# How can I match the impedances in this circuit?

Tags: amplifier, transmission-line, impedance-matching, signal-integrity, coax

I have a pre-amplifier with 93.1 Ω output impedance connected to a main amplifier with input impedance of 1000 Ω via 75 Ω co-axial cable.

The signals are very small pulses from a measurement device that are used for precision measurement and pulse counting.

I am concerned about mismatched impedances causing reflections, distortion and attenuation. Can anyone please suggest how this circuit can be improved to prevent these effects?

[image]

Comment: How fast are the pulses, in terms of duration, rise time, fall time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent reflections from the high impedance receiver upsetting the pulse shape at the end of the coax, you should add a terminator like this: -

[image]

$$R_T = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{75} - \dfrac{1}{1000}} = \text{ 81.08 }\Omega$$

That solves the reflection problem but, the received signal will be attenuated by about 2:1 so, if this is too much you need to either increase the transmit gain or increase the receive gain.

There should be no problems with a transmit impedance mismatch providing connection distances to the coax are short and transmission rise and fall times or not too short. I won't guess what they may be of course.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed reply.

Would you mind explaining why the source impedance mismatch is unlikely to be an issue? Unfortunately I don't have enough experience of this measurement system to estimate the rise and fall time.

Comment: It's simple; if the connections to the send-end of the coax are short, then there will be no significant reflection. How short is totally dependent on you and your rise/fall-times. Of course you can do the same trick at the transmit end that I did at the receive end and add a resistor circa 386 ohms to ground/0 volts. @b7031719

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I have struggled to find a good source to explain the calculations you have used. Do you have any useful links that you can direct me to?

Comment: @b7031719 The calculations are just based on the formula for parallel resistors, since the input impedance of the receiver is effectively in parallel with the added matching impedance.  The reason that the transmit mismatch isn't as important is that the connection to the coax is presumably short, so transmission line effects for that short a distance are not going to be an issue in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment John. How is the attenuation calculated?

Comment: Imagine it is DC that is being attenuated. If the 81.08 ohm resistor is fitted, the load on the output is 75 ohm. Then attenuation is \$\frac{75}{93.1+75}\$

Comment: Thanks again for your help.